# Cypress wait for element update

Tags: cypress

I am trying to assert change of class of element. The flow is that I click on a button, then pick something from dropdown that appeared and based on that class of icon changes to picked color, so here after click on element, class 'none' is being changed to 'green'. The problem is that the class is checked before it's changed - when I add `cy.wait(500)` after click assertion works fine. However I do not want to use implicit wait. How should I approach it? I tried some things like timeout but none seem to work.

```
cy.contains('.user-info', 'Name Surname').find('component-name i').should('have.class', 'none');
cy.contains('.user-info', 'Name Surname').find('component-name button').click();
cy.get('.flag-dropdown').contains('Green').click();
cy.contains('.user-info', 'Name Surname').find('component-name i').should('have.class', 'green');
```

Comment: The `.should()` command will continuously retry the previous command until the assertion passes or until timeout. Are you certain the `component-name i` contains the `green` class?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timeout with `find` something like this:

```js
cy.contains('.user-info', 'Name Surname')
  .find('component-name i')
  .should('have.class', 'none')

cy.contains('.user-info', 'Name Surname').find('component-name button').click()

cy.get('.flag-dropdown').contains('Green').click()

cy.contains('.user-info', 'Name Surname')
  .find('component-name i', {timeout: 5000})
  .should('have.class', 'green')
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be that `.should('have.class', 'green')` isn't re-checking `cy.contains('.user-info', 'Name Surname')`.

I would try adding the class to the find selector

```js
cy.get('.flag-dropdown').contains('Green').click();
cy.contains('.user-info', 'Name Surname')
  .find('component-name i.green')          // try specifying class here
  .should('have.class', 'green');
```